# AngularJS directives: Why watcher is not triggered?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/guziwamu/1/edit)

Given the following two directives:

JS:

```
angular.module("Directives", []).directive("action", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      action: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.showDialog = false;

      var template = "<span dialog='showDialog'>Dialog</span>";

      element.append($compile(template)(scope)).on('click', function() {
        console.log("Setting showDialog to true");
        scope.showDialog = true;
      });
    }
  };
}).directive("dialog", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dialog: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.hide();

      scope.$watch('dialog', function(newValue) {
        console.log("dialog changed to " + newValue); // Not called on button click
      });
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<button action>Click Here</button>
```

Could you explain why setting `action`'s `showDialog` doesn't trigger `dialog`'s watcher?

Comment: Actually, when you click the button - 'dialog' in directive 'dialog' doesnt change - looks like it is not binded properly - maybe because the scope in $compile is not the same as scope in action->link? But I dont know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on()` is a jQuery method included in Angular's jqLite. The code inside the attached event handler lives outside of Angular, so you need to use `$apply`:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

For example:

```
element.append($compile(template)(scope)).on('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function () {  
    console.log("Toggling showDialog");
    scope.showDialog = !scope.showDialog;
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/guziwamu/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

i did some changes to a more common way of writing it and i moved the element.hide(); after the $watch registration and it worked fine

```
app.directive("action", function ($compile) {
function link(scope, element, attrs) {      
    var template = "<span dialog='showDialog'>Dialog</span>";

    element.append($compile(template)(scope)).on('click', function () {
        console.log("Setting showDailog to true");
        scope.showDailog = !scope.showDailog;
    });
}

return {
    link: link
};  
});

app.directive("dialog", function ($compile) {
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch(attrs.dialog, function (newValue) {            
        console.log("dialog changed to " + newValue); // Not called on button click
    });

    element.hide();
}

return {
    link: link
};
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

$scope.showDailog = false;
});
```

App JS:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

HTML:

```
<button action>Click Here</button>
        Show dialog: <input data-ng-model="showDailog">
```